# ¿Cómo marcar 2 puntos de datos específicos en un gráfico de acción del precio usando matplotlib en Python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, gráficas, ciencia-de-datos, visualización-de-datos

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente gráfico:

[image: acción del precio de btcusdt desde 2022-04-01 05:59:59.99 hasta 2022-05-13 21:59:59.99]

Dicho gráfico se creó utilizando el siguiente código de Python:

```
from binance.client import Client
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#personal API key and Secret Key from your Binance account

api_key = "your binance api key"
secret_key = "your binance secret key"

client = Client(api_key= api_key, api_secret= secret_key, tld= "com")

klines_btcusdt = client.get_historical_klines(symbol="BTCUSDT", interval="1h", start_str = "1648807200000", end_str="1653667199999")

df_btcusdt = pd.DataFrame(klines_btcusdt)

#drop unnecesary columns
df_btcusdt.drop(5, inplace = True, axis=1)
df_btcusdt.drop(7, inplace = True, axis=1)
df_btcusdt.drop(8, inplace = True, axis=1)
df_btcusdt.drop(9, inplace = True, axis=1)
df_btcusdt.drop(10, inplace = True, axis=1)
df_btcusdt.drop(11, inplace = True, axis=1)

# Rename the column names for best practices
df_btcusdt.rename(columns = { 0 : 'Start Date', 
                          1 : 'Open Price',
                          2 : 'High Price',
                          3 : 'Low Price',
                          4 :'Close Price',
                          6 :'End Date',
                          }, inplace = True)

# Convert Unix Time values to actual dates
df_btcusdt['Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_btcusdt['Start Date'], unit='ms')
df_btcusdt['End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_btcusdt['End Date'], unit='ms')
df_btcusdt = df_btcusdt[['End Date','Close Price']]
df_btcusdt = df_btcusdt.set_index('End Date', inplace=False)
df_btcusdt = df_btcusdt.astype({'Close Price': 'float'})

#visualising the price
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
plt.title('BTCUSDT Price')
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize = 8)
plt.plot(df_btcusdt.index[0:], df_btcusdt[0:])
```

Y me interesa marcar 2 puntos de datos específicos que son: `df_btcusdt[0:1]` y `df_btcusdt[1024:1025]`, es decir:

```
                         Close Price
End Date                            
2022-04-01 05:59:59.999     44646.16

                         Close Price
End Date                            
2022-05-13 21:59:59.999     30046.65
```

Pero no sé cómo hacerlo, probé cambiando la última línea de mi código por la siguiente:

```
plt.plot(df_btcusdt.index[0:], df_btcusdt[0:], markevery = [44646.16, 30046.65], marker="ro")
```

pero obtengo:

> **ValueError:** markevery=[44646.16, 30046.65] is iterable but not a valid numpy fancy index

Debería arrojar algo como esto:

[image: gráfico deseado]

¿Puedo obtener ayuda por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Únicamente debes obtener una lista con los valores de "X" y "Y" que deseas marcar y los graficas con [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html).

Los estilos disponibles por defecto los puedes revisar en [`matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle.html#matplotlib.markers.MarkerStyle).

Ejemplo genérico (Por razones de seguridad evitaste poner tus llaves y no puedo generar los mismos datos que tienes, por eso hice algo genérico):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array(
    [  99912.5,   99925. ,   99937.5,   99950. ,   99962.5,   99975. ,
       99987.5,  100000. ,  100012.5,  100025. ,  100037.5,  100050. ,
       100062.5,  100075. ,  100087.5,  100100. ])
Y = np.array(
    [-83.99371  , -81.08232  , -71.8163   , -71.90387  , -79.6107   ,
     -80.90104  , -14.79405  ,   3.740311 ,  -0.6665535, -78.68803  ,
     -81.49953  , -79.48487  , -74.36191  , -80.68216  , -79.98886  ,
     -83.16663  ])

plt.title("Gráfica X Y")
plt.xlabel("Valores en X")
plt.ylabel("Valores en Y")
plt.plot(X, Y)

#Creamos una lista con los elementos que deseamos marcar
#En este caso serían los índices 7 y 9 de los arreglos X y Y
x = X[[7,9]]
y = Y[[7,9]]

#Graficar las marcas
plt.plot([x], [y], 'v', color='red', ms=10)

#Mostrar el valor numérico
for i, j in zip(x, y):
    plt.text(i, j, "({:0.2f}, {:0.2f})".format(i, j))
```

Esto produce:

[image: Gráfica]

Comment: Hey, ¡muchas gracias! Creo que diste solución a mi problema, sin embargo, Sólo me queda una duda, qué significa `"({:0.2f}, {:0.2f})"` ? Entiendo que imprimes en la gráfica, los valores marcados dentro de paréntesis, pero no entiendo por qué usas `:0.2f`?

Comment: Para limitar el texto a 2 decimales